# Copy SceneKit Assets Error

Tags: ios, xcode, arkit

I've been programming an `ARKit` application using a beta version of Xcode 9. Now, I've downloaded the Xcode 9 GM, and after opening my project I am getting the following warning:

> Showing All Issues
>   /copySceneKitAssets: Failed to copy SceneKit assets because scntool failed to process the following resources:
>   /PathToProject/Project-XXX/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Project.app/art.scnassets/object/object.scn 52753.4513

It is followed by this error:

> Command /Applications/Development/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/copySceneKitAssets emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

...and this error:

> scntool: error: failed to convert file with failure reason: *** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds

All of these don't really seem to have any effect on my app, since I can still run it on my device.
I've switched back to Xcode 9 beta, but the errors remain.

Any idea how I can solve them?